# How to show SQL statements in Rails console like WEBrick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails WEBrick shows raw SQL statements for any ActiveRecord activities. How to enable that in the console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do this you have to enable logger, you could do this as follows.

Open the rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set :@logger, Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Have a look at this link:

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/292826666/display-activerecord-generated-sql-queries-in-the

Comment: You'll want to combine this with `if $0 == 'script/server'` so that the output doesn't pollute the tests or any rake tasks for exmaple.

Answer (score 3):

A similar way to achieve this without resorting to digging into `ActiveRecord` internals and using instance variables is to just access the `config` object that Rails gives you. Place this inside `config/application.rb`:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) if($0 == 'irb' || $0 == 'script/rails')
```

Answer (score 1):

- Go to your `console.rb`  location `/lib/rails/console.rb`
- Look for  `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set`
- Change it to following

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set :@logger, Logger.new(STDOUT)`