# has_and_belongs_to_many on oracle_enhanced adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know if this is an issue with the oracle_enhanced adapter. I have:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :manuals
end

class Manual < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rooms
end

class CreateJoinTableManualRoom < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :manuals, :rooms do |t|
      t.index [:manual_id, :room_id]
      t.index [:room_id, :manual_id]
    end
  end
end
```

When I create a new manual, it does not update my manuals_rooms join table.

```
class ManualsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_manual, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @manuals = Manual.all
    @rooms = Room.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @manual = Manual.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @manual = Manual.new(manual_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @manual.save
        format.html { redirect_to @manual, notice: 'Manual was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @manual }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @manual.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @manual.update(manual_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @manual, notice: 'Manual was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @manual.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_manual
      @manual = Manual.find(params[:id])
    end

    def manual_params
      params.require(:manual).permit(:name, :document, :room_ids => [])
    end
end
```

Logs

```
Started POST "/manuals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-20 09:12:12 -0400
Processing by ManualsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ntqqh1vU9zrGZuw3K8xNef440ktAixWj+6Cx20wrCRg=", "manual"=>{"document"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000001134643d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/d1/x0nbfyrj30bd_p33ds0f12_c0000gq/T/RackMultipart20140820-59361-1jkeynu>, @original_filename="103.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"manual[document]\"; filename=\"103.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "room_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
Unpermitted parameters: room_id
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "MANUALS" ("CREATED_AT", "DOCUMENT", "ID", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4)  [["created_at", Wed, 20 Aug 2014 09:12:12 EDT -04:00], ["document", "103.jpg"], ["id", 10021], ["updated_at", Wed, 20 Aug 2014 09:12:12 EDT -04:00]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/manuals/10021
Completed 302 Found in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

I changed `room_ids => []` to `room_id` and now I get:

```
  SQL (2.5ms)  INSERT INTO "MANUALS" ("CREATED_AT", "DOCUMENT", "ID", "ROOM_ID", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5)  [["created_at", Wed, 20 Aug 2014 09:20:43 EDT -04:00], ["document", "AMH_BW.jpg"], ["id", 10022], ["room_id", 3], ["updated_at", Wed, 20 Aug 2014 09:20:43 EDT -04:00]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/manuals/10022
Completed 302 Found in 56ms (ActiveRecord: 19.0ms)
```

manuals/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@manual) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :document %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :document %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%#= collection_select(:manual, :room_ids, Room.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :room_id, Building.order(:name), :rooms, :name, :id, :name_with_number, include_blank: true %>                            
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you suspect that Rails isn't sending the right SQL to your dbms then you can view the sql in the console, which is useful for debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731070/how-to-show-sql-statements-in-rails-console-like-webrick

Comment: Although, i think the problem is probably not due to your dbms adaptor.  Can you add the contents of `manual_params` as an edit to your post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here. Let me highlight them one by one:

### 1. Missing `multiple: true` option

`Room` and `Manual` have a *HABTM* association, i.e., *M-M relationship*.

As *@MaxWilliams* pointed out in his answer, Rails would expect an array of `room_ids` in the `params` hash and not a single value.

For that to happen you should allow the user to *select multiple `rooms`* in the form (Remember, its *M-M relationship*) by adding `multiple: true` as an `html` option to `grouped_collection_select` method in your `form`. And also, first argument should be `room_ids` instead of `room_id`.

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :room_ids, Building.order(:name), :rooms, :name, :id, :name_with_number, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
```

### 2. Permit `room_ids` as an Array

As `room_ids` would now be passed as an array in the `params` hash because of *Change #1* above, it should be permitted as an `Array`.

```
def manual_params
  params.require(:manual).permit(:name, :document, :room_ids => [])
end
```

### 3. Remove `room_id` from `manuals` table

As per the shared logs in the question

```
SQL (2.5ms)  INSERT INTO "MANUALS" ("CREATED_AT", "DOCUMENT", "ID", "ROOM_ID", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5)  [["created_at", Wed, 20 Aug 2014 09:20:43 EDT -04:00], ["document", "AMH_BW.jpg"], ["id", 10022], ["room_id", 3], ["updated_at", Wed, 20 Aug 2014 09:20:43 EDT -04:00]]
```

I see that you have added `room_id` field to `manuals` table. Now that's a **No! No!**

You don't have a *1-M association* or a *1-1 association* between `Manual` and `Room` BUT have a *M-M association* between them with a join table `manuals_rooms` which already contains `room_id` and `manual_id` fields.

Bottom-line is that you need to *remove* `room_id` from `manuals` table.

Generate a migration for removing `room_id` as:

```
rails generate migration RemoveRoomIdFromManuals room_id:integer
```

Run `rake db:migrate` to migrate the changes.

This should take care of your issue. Let me know.

---

> I'm really starting to think that this may be an oracle thing

No! There is nothing wrong with the `oracle_enhanced adapter`. It's your code that is causing the issue.

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect your changes. I am now getting `OCIError: ORA-01007: variable not in select list: SELECT "MANUALS".* FROM "MANUALS" WHERE "MANUALS"."ID" = :a1 AND ROWNUM <= 1`

Comment: @Bruno I have made a change in #1 point, `f.grouped_collection_select` should be on `:room_ids` and not `:room_id`. I missed that one before.

Comment: @Bruno About the error, its actually coming in `show` action i.e. display logic, its a different question now not related to the creation issue. This one definitely looks like `oracle_enhanced` related issue. Which version of `oracle-enhanced` are you using?

Comment: @Bruno here is what Oracle docs says about ora-01007 error:http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01007_variable_not_in_select_list.htm

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thanks its working now. The show action is complaining because in the view I have `<%= @manual.room_id %>` I removed that and now it works.

Comment: @Bruno Now that you have removed the `room_id` field from Manuals, this code will not work.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I replaced `<%= @manual.room_id %>` in manuals/show.html.erb with `<%= @manual.room_ids %>` and it works...

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a habtm relationship, you would expect to get `params[:room_ids]` and for this to be an array.  The actual name of the input in the form should be `room_ids[]` - the array at the end tells rails to collect all params with the name `room_ids[]` and collect them into an array in `params[:room_ids]`.

So, in your rendered html you'd expect to see (if it was a checkbox for example) something like this:

```
<input name="room_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
```

If this isn't in your rendered html (look at the page with chrome inspector or similar) then you're not setting your form up right.  Please add the code for form in another edit to your post.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. I've added _form.html.erb to my post.

Comment: Hmm, i think there's an issue with your collection_select.  Can you add the rendered html for the form to another edit?

Comment: @MaxWiliams the collection_select works. I see in the params the correct room id when the form is submitted. I'm really starting to think that this may be an oracle thing. I feel like I've covered all the bases for creating a HABTM.